# How to disable Sonar-Check in codes

Tags: sonarqube

Some lines of codes don't need to be checked by Sonar (Sonarqube.org). How can I just disable checking on these lines? Is there any way like just addding annotation "@" to make these lines invisible for Sonar? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways. See [FrequentlyAskedQuestions-NOSONAR](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/faq/) and further down that page to see both a comment (//NOSONAR) and annotation (@SuppressWarnings) options, as well as some other ways to disable checking.

Comment: This is why answers which rely on links are less than useful. The link is now broken and when I find the equivalent page in the [current documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Frequently+Asked+Questions), I find no mention of using `@SuppressWarnings` there - I already know that `//NOSONAR` doesn't solve my current problem, but an annotation might. *8'(

Answer (score 0):

From official docs:

## How do I get rid of issues that are False-Positives?

> **False-Positive and Won't Fix** You can mark individual issues False Positive or Won't Fix through the issues interface. If you're using
>   Short-lived branch and PR analysis provided by the Developer Edition,
>   issues marked False Positive or Won't Fix will retain that status
>   after merge. This is the preferred approach.
>
> **//NOSONAR** Most language analyzers support the use of the generic mechanism: `//NOSONAR` at the end of the line of the issue. This will
>   suppress the all issues - now and in the future - that might be raised
>   on the line.